# Selecting unique row from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hope you guys can help as this has been bugging me a couple of days now. I'm trying to get the total number of unique rows from a table. For instance, the data in the table looks like this;

```
 user_1 | user_2 | date_added          | date_removed        
--------|--------|---------------------|---------------------
 1      | 2      | 2016-09-20 15:51:45 | 2016-09-24 09:15:32 
 1      | 3      | 2016-09-21 10:16:03 | 2016-09-29 00:46:44
 6      | 1      | 2016-09-23 05:48:59 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
 1      | 3      | 2016-09-30 09:57:16 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

What I want to find is the total number of rows that a user_id appears in (either column `user_1` or column `user_2`), where there is also only a single entry for that pairing of users (user pairings will always be in the same columns), and `date_removed` = `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

So if I search the table above for `user_id` '1', the total would be '1'. (Only 3rd line matches search critera);
where a search for `user_id` '2' would equal '0';
`user_id` of '3' would equal '0';
`user_id` of '6' would equal '1';

Hope that makes sense. Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

---- EDIT ----

This is the query i have so far, i've tried several ways inc joins etc, but this has got me closest so far, and its not the cleanest way im sure!

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE (`user_1` = '1' OR `user_2` = '1') 
GROUP BY `user_1`, `user_2` 
HAVING `count` < '2' AND MAX(`date_removed`) < '0000-00-00 00:00:01'
```

However, when as more data appears in the table, the result of the query looks like this:

```
count
-----
1
1
1
```

Where I want it to show:

```
count
-----
3
```

Comment: From your explanation, it looks like you are only searching on user_1. But it sounds like you want to search for the user_id in both user_1 and user_2. If that is the case a user_id of 1 would result in a count of 2. So a user_id of 6 or 1 would match on row 3. A user_id of 1 would match rows 3 and 4.... Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: the user_id would be searched in both columns (user_1 and user_2). Only line 3 will match search requirements for user 1 as although line 4 has '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for date_removed, the user pairing (1 & 3) also appear on line 2.

Comment: Can you insert in the question the SQL you have already tried? As @user3053392 pointed, the understanding is that more than one row would be found. Also, when user_id=3, it would also return 1 (the 4th row), from my understanding. I think we're missing something.

Comment: user_id of 3 would need to return 0 as the user pairing (1 & 3) already appears in the table (the 2nd line). Basicly im after the total number of rows which the user pairings only appear once (the pairings are 1 & 2, 1 & 3, 6 & 1 in the table above) and the date_removed = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. Therefore a search for user_id of 1, in the table shown would be '1'.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to achieve this.
I'm sending an option, creating a view to make it easier, but if you don't want to create a view, you can use its code in a subquery.

1. Create a view to union all possible combinations of user1, user2

   ```
   create view result as
   select user1, user2, date_removed from test
   union all
   select user2, user1, date_removed from test
   ```
2. Create a query

   ```
   select r.user1, r.user2
   from result r
   where
       r.date_removed = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
       and r.user2 not in (select r2.user2 
                           from result r2 
                           where r2.date_removed <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
   ```

Hope it helps you to solve it.